# Constructing the natural numbers without set theory.

Tags: analysis, definition, number-systems

As I understand it the idea of defining everything as sets is a relatively new idea in mathematics.  Does that mean there's a non-set theoretic definition of the natural numbers?  Could there be?

Comment: there is one way, I saw one time in a book, I don't remember it well, maybe Elliot Foundations.

Comment: With a function called n-admissible, which allows you to build adition and multiplication..

Comment: Yes, this is! The iteration Theorem.  https://books.google.com.pe/books?id=3domViIV7HMC&lpg=PP1&dq=foundations%20of%20analysis&hl=es&pg=PR6#v=onepage&q=foundations%20of%20analysis&f=false

Comment: I think you'll find that before set theory, it wasn't even clear to people that the natural numbers *needed* to be constructed; they just *were.* However in the modern viewpoint, there are many ways of constructing $\mathbb{N}$. Hopefully, you will get some interesting answers that showcase this variety of approaches.

Comment: Note however that most approaches to defining $\mathbb{N}$ do in fact use set theory in some guise or another; just because the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ isn't the *usual* ZFC-style definition, does not mean we're not using set theory!

Answer (score 4):

One way to construct the natural numbers (without sets) is [type theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+type). We define an inductive type $\mathbb{N}$ with two constructors:

$$
1 : \mathbb{N}
$$
$$
S : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}
$$

Where $S$ "adds one" to a number. In this system $2$ is represented by $S(1)$, $3$ is represented by $S(S(1))$ etc. This is essentially a more direct implementation of the [Peano axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).

Comment: Indeed, and this is somewhat practical, from say, a programming point of view. I note dryly, that it is a bit unfair to use the symbol "$1$" as it appeals to the definition we have not yet made. There is also an implicit appeal to set theory in framing $S$ as a function (without set theory, it's unclear what $S: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ might actually *mean*). But, as a *symbol* we can use what we prefer, I have seen developments where $u$ is used, for example. The idea of "solitary" or "single" can surely be made on the basis of an appeal to intuition.

Comment: @DavidWheeler, one reason to start at $0$ is because $S^n(0) = n$ is prettier than $S^{n}(1) = S(n).$ But in a sense, you're right; the least element should perhaps be denoted $\bot$ to avoid any suggestions as to what number this *really* is.

Comment: @DavidWheeler There is no appeal to set theory, only type theory. A type theoretic function is of a very different nature than a set theoretic one (it is not constructed as a left total and right unique relation).

Comment: @JohnColanduoni, I think that's a false distinction. The default semantics of type theory over classical logic is usually taken to be set theory. The other option - to not have a default semantics - is just sloppy! How am I supposed to know whether or not the inference rules you've written down are reasonable if I don't know what mathematical structures you're trying to axiomatize?

Comment: @JohnColanduoni indeed, I believe it has been shown (somewhere) that the lambda-calculus which underlies type theory, is "essentially" equivalent to a categorical alternative to set theory (all we really care about with arrows is "passing the flow along").

Comment: @DavidWheeler, pretty sure I've read that the simply-typed lambda calculus is the internal logic of Cartesian closed categories.

Comment: @goblin I'm not sure what you mean. If you look at a particular type theory (e.g. Calculus of Inductive Constructions) there is no appeal to any set theory; it is defined as a rewrite system that is independent of either an external set theory or logic. ZFC is often appealed to for proofs of consistency (relative to ZFC of course), but this is irrelevant to the fundamental construction.

Comment: @JohnColanduoni, but the same can be said of ZFC! ZFC is defined without any appeal to any set theory, its defined as formal system that is independent of an external set theory etc.

Comment: @goblin Yes, but then how is my distinction between a type-theoretic function and a set-theoretic one false? $S$ cannot be constructed as a set of ordered pairs, because the elements of the pairs would involve $S$ itself. So the type-theoretic notion of a function clearly is of a very different nature, especially when we extend it to dependent function types.

Comment: @JohnColanduoni, I think we mean different things by "set theoretic." You identify the set-theoretic approach with ZFC, or at least with [material set theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/material+set+theory)...

Comment: ... whereas for me, Lawvere's ETCS is, fundamentally, a set theory. Check out his original article [here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fartscidirectory.case.edu%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F07%2FLawvere-ETCS.pdf&ei=UhRcVcezOejJmAXe_YHYCQ&usg=AFQjCNHI6gBAwhDm07fTHZPmoLBTgf5oog&sig2=p-mNfTEEr-dNCw1UOxKLIg&bvm=bv.93756505,d.dGY). The point, really, is that there's many approaches to axiomatizing the universe of sets, and we don't have to interpret the phrase "universe of sets" to mean "cumulative hierarchy."

Comment: @goblin I am aware of ETCS (and its distinction from material set theory), but I don't see how we need ETCS or any other set theory to construct a type theory. All I see is a rewrite system which stands just fine on its own, and never talks about sets, material or otherwise. There is of course some degree of similarity between ETCS and type theory (e.g. neither has a global membership relation), but neither needs the other. And once again, functions in ETCS are very different from those in type theory.

Comment: @JohnColanduoni, how are functions in ETCS very different from those in type theory? They're both primitives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23940/discussion-between-john-colanduoni-and-goblin).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a "naive" construction. A "natural number" is a sequence of (identical) marks. It doesn't really matter "which" mark you use (a vertical stroke, a star, a triangle, a circle or a letter from any alphabet are all acceptable choices). I shall use the letter x. So these are all examples of natural numbers:

xxxxxxx

xx

xxxxxxxxxxx

x

A new natural number is obtained from another by adding a single x at the end (either end, front or back, doesn't matter).

We define a way of making longer numbers from shorter ones, via concatenation:

xxxx $\oplus$ xxx = xxxxxxx.

In actual practice this operation sign is often omitted, as understood.

We define a second operation by taking "blocks" of marks (bi-directional arrays):

xxxx $\otimes$ xxx =

xxxx

xxxx

xxxx

which we convert to a string sequence by laying the rows end-to-end.

I leave it to you, dear reader, to see if the Peano axioms for $\Bbb N - \{0\}$ are satisfied.

Comment: I like this approach. One way to formalize it is the way John Colanduoni describes. Another way to formalize what you are saying is that $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ is the semigroup freely generated by $\{x\}$ In this latter approach, multiplication of natural numbers has to be defined, but addition is automatic.

Comment: $0 \in \mathbb{N}$! Blasphemy!

Comment: The traditional "work-around" to this, is to allow the "empty mark" (blank space).

Answer (score 2):

The natural numbers constructed in the category $\mathsf{Set}$ (objects are sets with functions as the arrows) are an example of a more general notion: that of a [natural numbers object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object) (NNO) in a topos (or a cartesian closed category). A topos can be thought of as a "universe" for doing mathematics, just as the category $\mathsf{Set}$ is used in classical foundations. The nlab article I linked to gives some explicit examples of NNO's in topoi other than $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: A more direct but equivalent construction can be found in Emily Riehl's CATEGORY THEORY IN CONTEXT.